# Getting right mouse coordinates on swt composite click

Tags: java, shell, user-interface, swt, mouseevent

I am implementing checkers graphics with SWT graphics. the board is a shell with a board picture as a backgroung and each piece is represent as a composite in a fit place (the composite has a image of the piece). I add a `MouseListener` to the shell.

[image]

I also have a method that translate mouse coordinates to a place in the board (for example: clicking in `(60,173)` mean choosing the square in the place `[1,4]`).

I tested the method in an empty board and it worked just fine but now when i add the pieces i cannot get coordinates from the mouse when clicking on a piece. 
So i added the same listener to each composite but now i get very strange coordinates when mouse click on it. Seem like the coordinates are in scale to the composite picture and not to the shell. Now my translate method work fine on empty squares click but getting very strange results on non empty squares click.

What should I do for fix it? 
How can i get a composite click coordinate in the board shell scale?

Comment: If you added a listener to each composite, don't you know where the user clicked on? Why do you need the coordinates?

Comment: I created the composites in a loop without controlling their locations. only set the bounds to fit the correct place in the board. I dont have an array of composites if that what you asking.
Can i use the listener to get composite location?

Comment: You can use it to get the composite itself if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You could translate all the display co-ordinates(where the mouse click occurred) into co-ordinates relative to the shell through shell.toControl() method. eg.,

```
Display display = new Display();
Shell shell = new Shell(display);
....

    @Override
    public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent e) {
        // Translates display co-ord to shell co-ord.
        shell.toControl(display.getCursorLocation());   
}
```

or have all your composite co-ordinates normalised into display co-ordinates through the
composite.toDisplay(Point compositeCoOrd) and then translate the display co-ord relative to the shell.

I came across these two handy methods when i had to fix a issue similar to yours. Hope this helps.